# Algebra involving expected values

Tags: probability

If $C = A + B$ (hence $\mathbb{E}[C]$ = $\mathbb{E}[A]$ + $\mathbb{E}[B]$) and $p(A = a) = 1$, are the following true?

1. $\mathbb{E}[C^2] = a^2 + 2a\mathbb{E}[B] + \mathbb{E}[B^2]$
2. $\mathbb{E}[C^3] = a^3 + 3a^2\mathbb{E}[B] + 3a\mathbb{E}[B^2] + \mathbb{E}[B^3]$

What I have so far: Since $p(A = a) = 1$, that implies that $A$ and $B$ are independent, right? Then for the first one, it trivially becomes true that $\mathbb{E}[C^2] = a^2 + 2a\mathbb{E}[B] + \mathbb{E}[B]^2$, but is it necessarily true that $\mathbb{E}[B]^2 = \mathbb{E}[B^2]$?

Comment: Did you mean to define $C$ as $C=A+B$, and not only define the expected value of $C$? My point is that by knowing only $E[C]$ you can't really deduce much about $E[C^2]$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that since $A$ is almost surely constant, then it is independent of everything. Now, 
$$
C^2=(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+2AB
$$
and hence
$$
{\rm E}[C^2]={\rm E}[A^2+B^2+2AB]=a^2+{\rm E}[B^2]+2a{\rm E}[B].
$$
You don't need to use that ${\rm E}[B]^2={\rm E}[B^2]$ (which in general isn't correct).

To calculate ${\rm E}[C^3]$ you simply expand $C^3$ and take expectation using the same reasoning as above.

Comment: So since $A$'s value is always fixed, that makes $A^2$ independent of everything as well, right? (i.e., $A^2$ and $B$ are independent, and $A$ and $B^2$ are independent, yes?)

Comment: @wemblem: Indeed, in fact every function of $A$ is independent of every other variable.